# My front end (android) uses Java AES encryption while the backend Api (NodeJS) uses CryptoJS

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I'm trying to perform simple encryption/decryption on an android app (Java). The back-end Api written in NodeJS uses cryptoJS for its encryption/decryption as below:

```
encryptRequest(responseBody) {
let cipherRequest: string = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
  requestBody,
  randomKey
);

return cipherRequest;
}
```

and the result comes out as:

encrypted:

`U2FsdGVkX19O+sxMy+7X2mPkUwx7/g8NBNyLj2K/XeTO/w8q5XPGDLP4iQOja4Y4XCR8fMDF1s4aMDhaUNDdgaXXBUcKazFk7sj7xiQ7h+jpan2ta43xkudvfVGTainO9vrSfznTsdjxa5Zmq3+kGYQZ2Eyt6lB8OHDPKFXcbRbR5M7puMnu/yGnBxOSN+N4qonANcOVLhV59aLG/J+eheVFfJOPYWZSc9NE5/tdbSvPO7FZdrHtPiTWVxkAlRigMETyBl71lz1JtyN3cs8PJw==`

decrypted:

{
   "username": "myusername",
   "accountType": "user",
   "platform": "mobile",
   "version": "7.0.0",
   "password": "vivcXZFIqICjQB32aKSnvcVibEnmpGskMCT6Fv7aWnw="
}

I am using this library https://github.com/scottyab/AESCrypt-Android to decrypt on the front end but the value returned is always null, using the same secret key.

**Android code**

```
try {
  AESCrypt.decrypt(randomKey, responseBody); // no value is returned
}catch (GeneralSecurityException e){

}
```

In what way, possibly without the library can I get the decrypted data, other solutions on researched posts seemed way to complicated and I could hardly understand.

Comment: Don't use poorly documented libraries like CryptoJS, it makes code very hard to port to other platforms.

Comment: Agree.  CryptoJS has almost zero documentation, and the documentation it *does* have is vague.  Why can you not use the built-in node `crypto` module?

Answer (score -2):

My approach would be 1) look up CryptoJS documentation, specifically their default AES configuration parameters 2) Mirror these parameters on java side. Shouldn't need a library assuming you aren't attempting anything fancy, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html should get you up and going in ~15 min.